# Join tables for getting values of the record in Oracle

Tags: oracle, join, left-join

I have a query in which I want to join one column which is `select link_id from table tbl_fiber_inv_job` to query below

```
SELECT job_id, job_progress_id, approv_reject_remark 
FROM tbl_fiber_inv_job_progress
WHERE job_progress_id IN ( 
     select MAX(job_progress_id) 
     from tbl_fiber_inv_job_progress 
     where job_id in  (select job_id 
                       from tbl_fiber_inv_jobs 
                       where upper(span_type) = 'ENTERPRISE' 
                       AND link_id IN ('DLHI_4298')
                     )
     group BY JOB_ID
    ) order by job_id
;
```

How can I do this?

Comment: @APC: I want to get `link_id` in outer most query for getting remarks again each link_id. but i am unable to do so

Comment: This looks obvious, Does `tbl_fiber_inv_job`  have job_id column, if not than which column is common between tables.

Answer (score 2):

This solution uses WITH clause to pre-select the values from `tbl_fiber_inv_jobs`. This is used both to join to `tbl_fiber_inv_job_progress` in both the main query and the subquery.

```
with jobs as (select job_id, link_id
                       from tbl_fiber_inv_jobs 
                       where upper(span_type) = 'ENTERPRISE' 
                       AND link_id IN ('DLHI_4298')
                     )
SELECT p.job_id, p.job_progress_id, p.approv_reject_remark
       ,j.link_id 
FROM  jobs j
      join tbl_fiber_inv_job_progress p
          on p.job_id = j.job_id
WHERE p.job_progress_id IN ( 
     select MAX(p1.job_progress_id) 
     from tbl_fiber_inv_job_progress p1
          join jobs j1
     on p1.job_id = j1.job_id 
     group BY p1.JOB_ID
    ) 
order by j.job_id
;
```

---

I have made assumptions about your data model and business logic. If this solution doesn't suit you, please edit your question to provide more details.

Comment: the query is fine.. but the `approv_reject_remark` is coming multiple, I want the latest and remarks

Comment: Okay. Which version of Oracle are you using? Which column(s) indicates the latest? It might be helpful if you edited your question to include some sample input data and the desired outcome derived from that sample.